# In Go, when a function returns an error, are the other variables always its "zero" value?

Tags: go

I'm talking about the Go standard library:

```
output, err := abc.Xyz()
if err != nil {
    // by convention is `output` always its "zero" value?
}
```

Comment: By convention, but Go does not enforce it as a rule. In the standard lib I can't think of anything (off the top of my head) that doesn't follow this rule of thumb, however.

Comment: if the function expects err to be checked, it's usually not going to even define what the other values are.  the definition of the function needs to be specific enough to know this.  in some cases, non-nil err may have you going to the primary return value to find hints like error messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not always. For example,`io.Reader`:

> [Package io](https://golang.org/pkg/io/)
>
> [type Reader](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader)
>
> ```
> type Reader interface {
>         Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)
> }
> ```
>
> Reader is the interface that wraps the basic Read method.
>
> Read reads up to len(p) bytes into p. It returns the number of bytes
>   read (0 <= n <= len(p)) and any error encountered. Even if Read
>   returns n < len(p), it may use all of p as scratch space during the
>   call. If some data is available but not len(p) bytes, Read
>   conventionally returns what is available instead of waiting for more.
>
> When Read encounters an error or end-of-file condition after
>   successfully reading n > 0 bytes, it returns the number of bytes read.
>   It may return the (non-nil) error from the same call or return the
>   error (and n == 0) from a subsequent call. An instance of this general
>   case is that a Reader returning a non-zero number of bytes at the end
>   of the input stream may return either err == EOF or err == nil. The
>   next Read should return 0, EOF.
>
> Callers should always process the n > 0 bytes returned before
>   considering the error err. Doing so correctly handles I/O errors that
>   happen after reading some bytes and also both of the allowed EOF
>   behaviors.
>
> Implementations of Read are discouraged from returning a zero byte
>   count with a nil error, except when len(p) == 0. Callers should treat
>   a return of 0 and nil as indicating that nothing happened; in
>   particular it does not indicate EOF.
>
> Implementations must not retain p.

For example,

`readfile.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("readfile.go")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer f.Close()
    r := bufio.NewReader(f)

    fileLen := int64(0)
    buf := make([]byte, 0, 4*1024)
    for {
        n, err := r.Read(buf[:cap(buf)])
        buf = buf[:n]
        if n == 0 {
            if err == nil {
                continue
            }
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        // Do something with buf
        fileLen += int64(len(buf))

        if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("file length:", fileLen, "bytes")
}
```

If `err != nil` then, unless the documentation says otherwise, assume that all other values are undefined.